# UIWebView Page starts on different positions?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

In my project I have to display serveral Webpages. On top of the webView I've added an UIImageView to display a header. I've set up the positions and every mode equal.But the one page starts below the other page.
[This is what simulator displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnvO6.png)

The Webviews are porgrammatically the same, like you can see.

```
import UIKit

class SprintReviewViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SprintReview", ofType: "html")!)))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Like you can see in the code, I haven't done much with the webview. I only changed the URL!

The HTMLs are also in the same style. 
Start of HTML of the first screen

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="CSS.css">
            <h3>DAS DAILY SCRUM</h3>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
        <b>Zweck</b><br><br>
        ......
```

Start of HTML of the Second Screen

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="CSS.css">
    <h3>SPRINT REVIEW</h3>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<b>
Zweck
</b><br><br>
```

I don't know how to fix this.
I've done a little workaround by adding "< br>" tags to before the heading, but I don't like this.